# What's the best method to create a dictionary from outputs of multiple for loops

Tags: python

This is my code:

```
def get_coin_tickers(url):
    req = requests.get(url)
    # print(req.text)
    resp = json.loads(req.text)
    # print(resp.text)
    return resp


pair_a_list = ["BTC_USDT", "EOS_USDT", "ETH_USDT"]
pair_b_list = ["SOL_USDT", "MATIC_USDT", "SUSHI_USDT"]

for pair_a in pair_a_list:
    orderbook_url = f'https://api.pionex.com/api/v1/market/depth?symbol={pair_a}&limit=5'
    pair_a_prices_json = get_coin_tickers(orderbook_url)
    pair_a_ask = pair_a_prices_json['data']['asks'][0][0]
    pair_a_bid = pair_a_prices_json['data']['bids'][0][0]

for pair_b in pair_b_list:
    orderbook_url = f'https://api.pionex.com/api/v1/market/depth?symbol={pair_b}&limit=5'
    pair_a_prices_json = get_coin_tickers(orderbook_url)
    pair_b_ask = pair_a_prices_json['data']['asks'][0][0]
    pair_b_bid = pair_a_prices_json['data']['bids'][0][0]

keys = ['pair_a', 'pair_a_ask', 'pair_a_bid', 'pair_b', 'pair_b_ask', 'pair_b_bid']
values = [pair_a, pair_a_ask, pair_a_bid, pair_b, pair_b_ask, pair_b_bid]

mydict = {k: v for (k, v) in zip(keys, values)}
print(mydict)
```

I'm able to create a Dictionary but with only one Symbol-Pairs from each list. Which seems to be outputs from only the last symbol pairs  of both the lists:

```
{'pair_a': 'ETH_USDT', 'pair_a_ask': '1254.18', 'pair_a_bid': '1253.51', 'pair_b': 'SUSHI_USDT', 'pair_b_ask': '0.9815', 'pair_b_bid': '0.9795'}
```

I'm expecting to see a combined dictionary with values of both lists as keys (with their API-Values) in the final list (after) iterating through both lists using for Loops

Comment: after your for loop, your pair_a_ask has only the last value from the loop in it  Perhaps you want to zip the lists together first.

Comment: Making _all_ your text bold makes your question _less_ readable, and looks like you're shouting at us.

Comment: OK, if you @Pranav Hosangadi say so. I'm new here and if you notice during the process of creating a question, all titles are in bold "Title" , "What are the details of your problem?", "What did you try and what were you expecting?". I followed the similar format. I recommend that you do not consider anything personal and focus on the challenges related to the coding portion.

Comment: Thank you for quick reply @JonSG. I'm relatively new to Python and on Stack Overflow as well. Everyone's help is much appreciated.

Comment: There is a difference between a title (which is usually a few words, and should be emphasized, so it's fine for it to be bold), and _literally all the text in your question_. Don't worry, I didn't take it personally though :)

Comment: I found a solution with the suggestion from @JonSG. His inputs were much more productive, than **BOLD** this and **BOLD** that :-)

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution to my question based on suggestion from @JonSG, plus adapted to the suggestion. I've included the code below for others to use as and if the need arises.

```
for pair_a_list, pair_b_list, pair_c_list in zip(pair_a_list, pair_b_list, pair_c_list):
orderbook_a_url = f'https://api.pionex.com/api/v1/market/depth?symbol={pair_a_list}&limit=1'
pair_a_prices_json = get_coin_tickers(orderbook_a_url)
pair_a_ask = pair_a_prices_json['data']['asks'][0][0]
pair_a_bid = pair_a_prices_json['data']['bids'][0][0]
my_dict_a = {
    'pair_a_ask': pair_a_ask,
    'pair_a_bid': pair_a_bid
}

orderbook_b_url = f'https://api.pionex.com/api/v1/market/depth?symbol={pair_b_list}&limit=1'
pair_b_prices_json = get_coin_tickers(orderbook_b_url)
pair_b_ask = pair_b_prices_json['data']['asks'][0][0]
pair_b_bid = pair_b_prices_json['data']['bids'][0][0]
my_dict_b = {
    'pair_b_ask': pair_b_ask,
    'pair_b_bid': pair_b_bid
}

orderbook_c_url = f'https://api.pionex.com/api/v1/market/depth?symbol={pair_c_list}&limit=1'
pair_c_prices_json = get_coin_tickers(orderbook_c_url)
pair_c_ask = pair_c_prices_json['data']['asks'][0][0]
pair_c_bid = pair_c_prices_json['data']['bids'][0][0]
my_dict_c = {
    'pair_c_ask': pair_c_ask,
    'pair_c_bid': pair_c_bid
}

# (Use either option below.)
# my_dict = {**my_dict_a, **my_dict_b, **my_dict_c}
# my_dict = my_dict_a | my_dict_b | my_dict_c
```